# What the floor is exactly?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry

I came across this question:

> A rectangular floor is fully covered with square tiles of identical size. The tiles on the edge are white and tiles in interior are red. Number of white tiles is the same as the number of red tiles. Find the possible values of the number of tiles along on edge of the floor.

I thought of this diagram ->

[image: rough diagram for math question]

So, number of white tiles:  $x + x + y + y + 4\ (\text{the corner blocks})$

And number of red tiles:  $xy$

And given that both are equal:

$$\Rightarrow 2x + 2y + 4 = xy$$

$$\Rightarrow x + y + 2 = \frac{xy}{2}$$

I can't seem to understand what to do next. Can someone please help.

Thank you.

Comment: You're on the right track. Try to solve the equation for one varable (say $y$), and keep in mind that valid solution pairs $(x,y)$ have to satisfy $x,y\in\mathbb N$.

Comment: @AlexR Using trial and error ?

Comment: You can use some tricks to find out about divisibility a priori. you'll want all numbers $x$ which satisfy $$(x-2)|(x+2)$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Continuing from you first equality:
$$\begin{align*}
\Rightarrow 2x+4 & = (x-2)y\\
\Rightarrow y & = \frac{2x+4}{x-2} \\
& = 2 \frac{x+2}{x-2}
\end{align*}$$
Proceed by finding which values of $x$ yield natural numbers $y\in\mathbb N$:
1. $x>2$, since $y$ must be positive
2. $x=3 \Rightarrow y = 10$ is a solution
3. $x=4 \Rightarrow y=6$ is a solution
4. $x=5 \Rightarrow y=\frac{14}3$ is no solution
5. $x=6 \Rightarrow y=4$ is a solution (*pattern*?)
6. $x=7 \Rightarrow y=\frac{18}5$ is no solution
7. $x=8 \Rightarrow y=\frac{10}3$ is no solution
8. $x=9 \Rightarrow y=\frac{22}7$ is no solution
9. $x=10 \Rightarrow y=3$ is a solution

These solutions, $\mathbb L = \{(3,10), (4,6), (6,4), (10,3)\}$ are the only solutions, because
$$\frac{x+2}{x-2} > \frac{x+3}{x-1} = \frac{(x+1)+2}{(x+1)-2} \searrow 1$$
That means for $x>10, y<3$, but since $y>2$, we will not get any further natural solutions.

Comment: I tried some quick guesses. If $x$ equals 3, 4, 6, then $y$ becomes 10, 6, 4. But shouldn't there be only one answer to this question?

Comment: Oh! You gave all guesses with your edit

Comment: 10 / 2 + 1 or 6 / 2 + 1 => Is this the pattern?

Comment: I'll show you why those are the only solutions.

Comment: So, exactly, in the question, I can give any one of the answer and be correct ?

Comment: It says "find" (all) "the possible values", so you have to give all solutions.

Answer (score 3):

Your equation becomes $(x-2)(y-2)=8$: now use the prime factorization of $8$ to deal with all the possible cases.

Comment: That's a cool approach as well :) (+1)

Comment: So, how does one get to that equation: $$2x + 4 = (x - 2)y$$ $$x + 2 = \frac{(x - 2)y}{2}$$ Can you please explain how does your equation come? Thanks.

Comment: $2x + 2y + 4 = xy \implies xy -2x -2y =4 \implies xy -2x -2y +4=8$ and then you factorize the first member.